# Result not null in my code, if "sorIndex" is invalid

Tags: java, null, notnull

I would need some guidance from You, at the moment I have this challenge with this exercise:

The aim of this code would be, to split a `String`(`szoveg`) to rows and give back the result `row(sorIndex)` as a result, if `sorIndex` is in the range of the `String` Array(String szoveg is splitted into this array).

If the requested number of the row is not in the valid range(0-length of the array) it should give back a `null` value. The IDE for testing the excercise returns a mistake, which is the following(Hungarian + English):

> "A getSor() metódus nem működik jól. Nem létező sorIndexet megadva
> null-t kell visszaadjon a metódus. A konstruktor paramétere:"
>
> "The getSor() method is not working properly. Given a not valid
> sorIndex, the method should return null. The parameter of the
> constructor:" -there is nothing after this part in the IDE.

```
 public String getSor(int sorIndex) {

        int sorok= szoveg.split("\n").length;

        String sor;

        if (sorIndex >= 0 && sorIndex <= sorok) {  

            String[] stringTomb = new String[sorok];

            stringTomb = szoveg.split("\n");

            sor = stringTomb[sorIndex];

        } else {

            sor = null;

      }

        return sor;

    }
```

Does anyone have any idea where did I made the mistake?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message tells you that if an invalid `sorIndex` is passed, then a `null` should be returned. This means that instead of getting into the `else` branch in your logic, it goes into the `if` in an invalid manner.

The reason of this is that arrays are 0-indexed, so you should compare against rows (`sorok`) in a srict manner:

```
if (sorIndex >= 0 && sorIndex < sorok) {
```

That should fix the issue. However, your code computes `split` several times and is superfluous. I would refactor it to:

```
public String getSor(int sorIndex) {
    if (szoveg == null) return null; // Handling the case when szöveg is not properly initialized
    String stringTomb[] = szoveg.split("\n");
    return ((sorIndex >= 0) && (sorIndex < szoveg.length)) ? stringTomb[sorIndex] : null;
}
```

I used the ternary operator to make this more readable, concise and short.

Comment: Thank you so much, it solved the issue.
Really appreciated! :)